# How can I get back lost internet access on Android 4.x or lower?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, certificates, https

I have an Acer A500 tablet running Android 4.0.3. Trying this after not using for some time I find it can't access most websites, getting "Webpage not available" in Opera Mini browser. I have found an interesting web page (using my desktop) at [Android Police - Many websites will stop working on older Android versions in 2021](https://www.androidpolice.com/2020/11/07/many-websites-will-stop-working-on-older-android-versions-in-2021/).

Following up a link on this page, it says there has been a workaround by Let's Encrypt which will last till 2024, and doesn't need users to make any change. If that's so, it doesn't work for me. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 2):

The problem with the root-CA certificate is not the only one you are facing:

Devices with Android version 4.4 and before have problems accessing a lot of https sites because they do not support TLS 1.2. More and more web sites require that TLS version now as the older versions (SSLv3 TLS1.0 TLS1.1) have known security problems and there is a recommendation to not use them anymore.

There is a workaround where app authors can implement a workaround to include a custom TLS implementation. But AFAIK that requires at least Android 4.1.

Therefore there are multiple reasons why your tablet is EOL. You can try to flash a custom ROM (e.g. one with 5.1 to extend it a little longer but that will get you only a short delay).