# WIFI ON but Play fails "No internet connection. Make sure WiFi ..."

Tags: google-play-store, 4.2-jelly-bean, networking, google-play-services

Recently i decided to check for app updates and Play refuses to work and popup the error *"No internet connection. Make sure WiFi or mobile data is turned on."*

However WIFI is enabled and internet work fine for apps like fdroid.

Maybe the issue is due to the fact that it is an old android 4.2 but  Play services were updated 03/2019 and they are v 15.0.90

Is android 4 still supported by Play? ideas? other app stores?

And there are no alternatives as LineageOS or custom ROMs for this device

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get back lost internet access?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/239339/how-can-i-get-back-lost-internet-access)

Comment: Also, [Google Play Services stops supporting Android <4.3](https://www.androidauthority.com/android-jelly-bean-eol-1641403/).

Comment: First, what is your device❔❔?.

Comment: Its is an old S. Galaxy but Internet is working, and depending on the webbrowser you can receive warnings or error due certifications but WIFI is working fine. It is just Play producing a wrong and confusing error. I suppose soon PLay will definitely stop working as @AndrewT. said so I've installed aptoide app store