# Cannot install/replace Android OS on Samsung S3

Tags: adb, odin

I have a corrupt version of Android on my S3 phone: WiFi signal is 100% but almost zero internet connection.
So I found a binary: S968CUDUAMH1_S968CTFNAMH1_S968CUDUAMH1_HOME.tar.md5 which is good(?) for my S3.

[image: ADB Command Line]

ODIN Report
[image: Odin Log]

I completely uninstalled everything relevant and reinstalled without errors or anomalies in Device Manager.

But am still in the same place. ADB sees phone connected but will not program so I'm missing something somewhere.

@alexcx suggested ODIN requires download mode. Please explain. I also looked at your XDA link but that seems to require Internet connection which I don't (nearly, see below) have.
Your link to lost internet on Android 4 or lower, I'm afraid, won't help since again I don't have internet access.
Your comment that you're pretty sure I have internet access may be [just] partially true.  Note my router connection is five bars but internet connection may be just one, hard to be sure, since I can intermittently connect to google but 99.9% of the connections time out.
So I'm assuming it's an OS issue so rooting and replacing OS just might resolve it.

Ah! @alexcs, your final comment led me to load ODIN and check the fist step when I should see (first) ID:COM with something like 0:[COM6] underneath but I don't.. see my pic.
Also no <ID:0/006> Added! in the Log.
So if ADB can see my phone why can't ODIN?  I have AFAIK have Samsung drivers loaded with no errors in DM.

Comment: Devices with yellow exclamation mark in device manager are usually not usable e.g. because of missing/wrong driver. You need to fix that first.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why do apps stop supporting older Android versions after some time?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/234334/why-do-apps-stop-supporting-older-android-versions-after-some-time)

Comment: Possibly related: [How can I get back lost internet access on Android 4.x or lower?](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/239339/44325)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What are possible consequences of not installing updates](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/220188/what-are-possible-consequences-of-not-installing-updates)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [If I buy the cheapest possible Android smartphone today, how long can I keep it without having to buy a new one?](https://android.stackexchange.com/questions/236538/if-i-buy-the-cheapest-possible-android-smartphone-today-how-long-can-i-keep-it)

Comment: https://androidmtk.com/flash-samsung-stock-rom-using-odin

Comment: Edited my original post. Please see.

Comment: btw you didn't mention that you factory reset the device. a factory reset has same effect as flashing stock ROM, it is the first thing you should try. you only mention wifi, but what about mobile data?

Comment: The file you point is hash of the original file. You should find the file w/o .md5 extention

Comment: I think @alecxs inferred the actual problem. A faulty modem. A pretty brick :~((

Comment: @RomeoNinov `tar.md5` file is fine. it is a tarball archive, not a hash. That's how samsung provides firmware